# Critical points of the function $y=x^{\frac{a}{x} - \frac{a-b}{x}}$?

Tags: calculus

Consider
$$
y = x^{\frac{a}{x} - \frac{a-b}{x}} \;,
$$
where $a$ is a series of number and $b$ is a constant.

I cannot get it correct by graphing them and comparing with the first derivative method. The critical points should increase with $a$, but I cannot get it. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: $$
\frac{a}{x} - \frac{a-b}{x} = \frac{b}{x}
$$